# List of Employees who are not in the list one day before and one day after weekend

Tags: sql-server, time-and-attendance

I need list of those employees who are absent one day before and one day after weekend in a week......like if some is absent in Friday and present on Monday should not be included in the list

[image]

Comment: Picture is included in question.

Comment: What is your query and the error you are getting?

Comment: Are  you using a Calendar table?

Comment: When you say absent on the Friday and the Monday, does it need to be *for the same weekend*? I.e. if they are absent one Friday, in the following Monday, but then absent the following Monday, they would not be included.

Comment: Yes, those people who doesn't have record in friday of one week and Monday of next week.

Answer (score 1):

Use datepart(weekday, ) to fetch all records relative to monday and friday.

Have a look at [SET DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql) function too.

```
select *
from   your_table
where  datepart(weekday, Date) = 5 
or     datepart(weekday, Date) = 1;
```

Comment: Sunday is 1 while Monday is 2, isn't?

Comment: @anonyXmous it depends on SET DATEFIRST

Comment: But by absent I mean they don't have record on those days

Answer (score 0):

This will list all employee id that are absent on a Friday and the following Monday (+1 week).  I set-up a calendar week from mininum date to maximum date from the table and get only Friday and Monday.  Then get all empid that has no attendance in any of those dates.

```
with caldte as (
SELECT  dateadd(day, rn - 1, t.mindte) as dates,
        datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, rn - 1, t.mindte)) as weekday,
        datepart(wk, dateadd(day, rn - 1, t.mindte)) as weeknum
FROM    ( 
  select row_number() OVER ( order by c.object_id ) AS rn
  FROM sys.columns c) rns, 
  (select min(dte) as mindte, max(dte) as maxdte 
   from tbl) t
    WHERE   rn - 1 <= datediff(day, t.mindte, t.maxdte)
    and datepart(weekday, dateadd(day, rn - 1, t.mindte)) in (2, 6)
  )
select distinct empid  
from tbl
where empid not in (
  select t.empid
  from caldte c, tbl t
  where c.dates = t.dte)
order by empid
```